# Parent and Child table question

Tags: database-design

Another question on the photo organisation and storage app design I am working on for my class: the specifications mention that people are able to be recorded in the database even if they don't appear in any photograph and that a location can be recorded even if there aren't any photographs associated with them. I'm not sure I understand what this would mean. Would you say this would mean the person and location tables should be parent tables to the photo table or am I missing something?

Comment: locations and persons should be a 1:n relation and so would egt a relationship table betweenthe tables. and oif you dont add an entry in that relation table, no loacation or person is added

Comment: So you're saying a photo is the parent to both person and location tables? But then why do they say the bit about them being able to be recorded even if there aren't any photos associated with them?

Comment: i can't tell you why, because i don't know the background, but with my approach it doesn't matter, you can add every person to a photo. Lets say you photograph a house of babara streisand , then you would add babata streisand to the foto even when she is not visible

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Possibly also that a user of the app could be a person that exists in the system even without being in a photo, and they themselves could be associated with a location. Also, a photo album could have several locations even if photos themselves aren't all associated with a location, I guess. Thanks nbk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it comes to this:

Your photo is abourt a house, that belongs to a person. your photo has no persons in iit, but it still belongs to the person, so you can add a relationship to the photo.

The same goes for for locations the Washington Monument  is located between  Capitol and Lincoln Memorial so you can add a relationship between tose .